# Generating Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a list of a href's and I would like to create a drop down list from it.

How can i accomplish this without using jQuery?

I'm new to javascript...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
for (var i=0; i<hrefs.length; i++) {
  var link = hrefs[i];
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = hrefs[i];
  option.innerHTML = i + ": " + hrefs[i]; // this is the label
  select.appendChild(option);
}
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

I'm not sure if the label is right; it depends on what you mean by a list of hrefs and what you want to do with the label. I'm assuming you have an array of links like ["http://google.com", ...].

Answer (score 3):

If you have JavaScript 1.6 you can do something like this:

```
var hrefs = ['http://stackoverflow.com', 'http://example.com'],
  select = document.createElement("select"),
  str = hrefs.map(function(l){
    return '<option>'+l+'</option>'
  });
select.innerHTML = str.join('');
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

You can mimic .map with

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

(via MDC - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: BTW, you can edit `return '<option>'+l+'</option>'` to fit your needs. Its general idea...